# Which of the original Kenner Star Wars vehicles were to the correct scale of the action figures?

Tags: star-wars, toys, merchandise

The *Star Wars* action figures as made by Kenner in the late '70s and early '80s were on a 1:18 scale. In fact, though they were not the first to use the scale, their popularity established the scale as a standard.

In contrast, [the All Terrain Armored Transport](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport), commonly referred to as the AT-AT Walker, with an in-universe height of a bit over 22m, has a toy model that stands at about 50cm, making for a scale somewhere around 1:40. This becomes apparent in its head, that is crewed by at least three in the films, but barely fits two in the toy.

[The T-47 "Snowspeeder"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Snowspeeder) toy on the other hand, seems to be to scale when compared to the action figures.

This made me wonder, which —if any— of the vehicles and playsets of those made by Kenner up to the mid '80s are on the same scale as the action figures, 1:18?

Or is the scale of each vehicle and playset available somewhere?

I'm not interested in the Mini-Rigs or really anything not seen in the films, since their size and thus their scale can not be meaningfully compared to a counterpart in a film.

---

<sub>This question *is* asking for a list, however, it is [a *finite* list](http://theswca.com/images-toys/figuretoys/index.html), which is allowed.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

**I think the landspeeder is perhaps the closest to scale.**

A movie still:
[image]

An image of the toy:
[image]

---

**Obviously not to scale are:**

the X-Wing fighter, Tie fighter, Millennium Falcon, ATAT

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about the Death Star?   That's to scale, right?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - No, not really. Assuming a diameter of 600km, a Death Star playset would have to be more than 30km in diameter (and include over a million action figures!!!) in order to maintain the 1:18 scale. The toy shown clearly depicts a couple key scenes in a very compact space: the retractable bridge, the trash compactor, the brig. As with all the bigger SW toys, they are scaled down undoubtedly to keep costs reasonable while still allowing for imaginations to fly free. Even the floor to ceiling height of the levels is not to the grand scale of the original structure.

Comment: I remember being ENORMOUSLY disappointed when a friend told me they had the Death star play set and I saw that was the entirety of it.